# OpenMP: reduction and sharing

Tags: c++, openmp

I have following code, which is resulting into erroneous output.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i,piold) shared(pi,sign)
{
#pragma omp for reduction(+:pi) schedule (static)
  for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        piold = pi;
        pi += sign/(2*i+1);
        sign=-sign;
  }
}
  pi = 4*pi;
```

I am a bit lost as I am new to OpenMP. What is confusing me is how to pass `sign`, `pi` and `piold` between the threads? They cannot be shared as alternate iterations need different values. So one way is to have iterations separated as odd and even, but that seems very inefficient.

Any suggestions in this case?

Comment: Assuming `sign` and `i` are both integer variables and `sign` initially is `1` or `-1`, `sign/(2*i+1)` will give `0` for all but the first iteration. Also, while I don't know about OMP, declaring `sign` as both private and shared seems contradictory to me.

Comment: sign private and share was a mistake. I have corrected my code here.

Comment: Is the wrong result you get "pi=4"?

Comment: There is a loop carried dependency in `sign = -sign;` and `sign` being shared results in data races between the threads, therefore the wrong result. Make `sign` private and compute it in each iteration based only on the value of `i`, for example, as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like you try to use [Leiniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) to approximate pi.

- C++ support declaring iterative in for scope, so remove i from the private.

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
- sign can be know base on odd/even property of i, so use (i & 1) check instead and remove the sign from the private

  ```
      int sign = 1 - (i & 1);
      pi += (sign == 1 ? 1f : -1f) / (2 * i + 1);
  ```
- piold doesn't affect final result pi, remove from the private

You can read http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/ for more. Since I don't have a compiler support OpenMP now so I can't test and give you the sample code. But I suggest two case:

- Separate (+) and (-) of formula into 2 threads by odd/even of i using openmp section. You will have two section

double plus = 0.0;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        plus += (4 * i + 1);
```

and

```
double minus = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
   minus += (4 * i + 3);
```

then

```
pi = plus - minus;
```

- Use the reduction clause for pi

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did some code modification (shared list) and with increasing iteration count I get better results. I am trying to understand how to have if condition check for sign inside for loop.